# Fragments disappear when rotated

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, rotation

I’ve added the fragments using java.

when I open the app in portrait mode it works.

[image: ScrrenShot]

if I rotate the fragment just disappear.

[image]

but if I close the app,  then rotate the phone,  and then open the app again, it works.

[image]

i have two different layouts one for portrait mode other for landscape mode,
both with the same name, i have the layout for portrait in the "layout" folder, and the layout for landscape on "layout-land" folder.

it seems like i am forgetting something, sincerely i am new on android development.

Activity:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListFragment frag = new ListFragment();

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.LIST_LAYOUT,frag,"LIST");
        transaction.commit();

    }
```

Fragment :

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{


    ListView List;
    Communicator communicator;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mlistfragment,container,false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        communicator = (Communicator) getActivity();

        List = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.StrListButtons,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        List.setAdapter(adapter);


        List.setOnItemClickListener(this);


    }
```

Comment: when orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated. So is fragment as fragment is hosted by activity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You actually don't need to add the `Fragment` every time the `Activity` is created; the `FragmentManager` maintains them automatically. You should wrap the code which does the `FragmentTransaction` in an `if (savedInstanceState == null)` check, so that it is only executed the first time the `Activity` is created. For example:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.list_layout, new ListFragment(), "LIST")
                        .commit();
}
```

Comment: I have the if statement, but still content disappears, any idea why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231235/activity-content-disappears-when-rotating

Answer (score 0):

An activity is usually recreated after the orientation change. 
You can try using the onSaveInstanceState() method to preserve the data.

Please refer this link for more details.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ConfigurationChanges

Answer (score -2):

Hello Hi could you try Implementing onResume() and calling 
this block of code from there

```
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.add(R.id.LIST_LAYOUT,frag,"LIST");
    transaction.commit();
```

also override onsaveinstancestate()

Answer (score -3):

Try to use setRetainInstance(true); in your fragment's onCreate method.